# WPF Slider Design

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to use a slider like this [image: Like This]

I want that slider to adjust accordingly to the value provided to it.
So far I am only able to apply background with gradient effect, but not able to get this effect. Please help me for this by providing me the style code.

```
<Slider>
   <Slider.Background>
      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
         <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
         <GradientStop x:Name="WhiteOffset" Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5"/>
         <GradientStop x:Name="GrayOffset" Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
      </LinearGradientBrush> 
   </Slider.Background>
</Slider>
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about post the whole element and related resources? Where is the `<Slider>` tag?

Comment: it is like `<Slider><Slider.Background>Above Code</Slider.Background></Slider>`

Comment: Write a complete question

Comment: @BenjaminPaul it is the complete question i have no idea about slider style so i need of the style which helps me to get the slider like above Pic

Comment: How about editing the question with the new information...

Comment: First google result http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/customize-a-slider-in-wpf-step-by-step-tutorial/

Comment: i have checked this but needed something else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the custom handles you need to [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa544582%28v=office.14%29.aspx) the [control template of the slider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753256%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For the background you can achieve this effect with three `LineaGradientBrush`es layerd on top of each other. the first one is for the red-yellow-green gadient, the the 2nd one is for the white lines (gradientstops transparent and white, `SpreadMethod` set to `Repeat`) and the 3d one for the glossy effect).

```
  <Slider Height="50">
    <Slider.Background>
      <VisualBrush>
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
          <Grid>
            <Rectangle Width="1" Height="1">
              <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="1,0">
                  <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0" />
                  <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                  <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
              </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Width="1" Height="1">
              <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0.1,0" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
                  <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.5" />
                  <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5" />
                  <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.55" />
                  <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.55" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
              </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Width="1" Height="1">
              <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
                  <GradientStop Color="#11FFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#22FFFFFF" Offset="0.5" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#11000000" Offset="0.5" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#11000000" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
              </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
          </Grid>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
      </VisualBrush>
    </Slider.Background>
  </Slider>
```

This above background looks like this:

[image: gardient background]

Comment: and what about thumb? and this control is changing the background only not the slider area.

Comment: As I mentioned you will have to learn to write custom control templates (override the default control template of the `Slider` control). Follow the two links I posted.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, where I wanted the track of my bar to be a gradient. You can override the default `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` resource to change the color of the selection area.

```
<Slider Name="WPF Gradient Slider Bar" Margin="5px" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"
        IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True" 
        SelectionStart="0" SelectionEnd="100">
        <Slider.Resources>
             <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                      <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="Cyan" Offset="0.75"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.5"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.25"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
              </LinearGradientBrush>
         </Slider.Resources>
</Slider>
```

Result:

[image: WPF Gradient Slider Bar]

Comment: Trying to use your solution, for some reason the gradient just disappears if I don't use the selection range! Also, a very short distance at the very left of the slider's track doesn't get colored! any idea about that?